# how can a Flutter application receive low memory notifications?

Tags: flutter, memory-management

I have a data cache. It is expensive to fetch some of the data.. other data is quite disposable. The data can be quite large and could conceivably cause the OS to ask apps to free memory.

Android has onTrimMemory() and IOS has applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(). Is there a flutter equivalent?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: hmm.. i was rather hoping it wouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter WidgetsBindingObserver class provides a method to detect low memory, as demonstrated in [this article](https://www.refactord.com/guides/flutter-application-system-manager).

Comment: next time you should expand your answer instead of pointing to an external link with no explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The widget must implement the `WidgetsBindingObserver` and override `didHaveMemoryPressure`, like in the following example:

```
class _HomePageState extends BaseState<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didHaveMemoryPressure() {
    print('didHaveMemoryPressure');
  }

}
```